# Convert Matlab to Python, problem with rescaling

Tags: python, image, matlab, numpy, porting

I'm trying to convert the following code from from MATLAB to Python:

```
x = [0:n/2-1, -n/2:-1];
[Y,X] = meshgrid(x,x);
S = (X.^2 + Y.^2)*(2/n)^2;
```

This is what I currently implemented:

```
x = [np.arange(0, 256/2-1), np.arange(-256/2, -1)]
[Y,X] = np.meshgrid(x, x)
S = (X**2 + Y**2)*(2/256)**2
```

If i use it like this the shape of my matrix is (254,254), however it needs to be (256,256)

I also tried changing the first line it to:

```
x = [np.arange(0, 256/2), np.arange(-256/2, 0)]
```

This way my matrix is the right size, however I don't think that this is the right implementation because the resulting image doesn't look right.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the following line:

```
x = [np.arange(0, 256/2-1), np.arange(-256/2, -1)]
```

The last element of x would be -2, when python initialise an array it will exclude the value you specific in your second argument, -1 in the case. On top of that, how you initialise x would be different than the vector in MATLAB, it will generate a list with two elements, with an array of 127 elements in the first index. Please also be aware python indexing starts at 0 and MATLAB indexing starts at 1.

```
len([np.arange(0, 256/2-1), np.arange(-256/2, -1)]) # 2

len([np.arange(0, 256/2-1), np.arange(-256/2, -1)][0]) # 127
```

If you change the first line to be:

```
x = np.append(np.arange(0, 256/2),np.arange(-256/2, 0))
```

x will then match the vector in MATLAB and the subsequence will be correct.